# Error when uploading to heroku git

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

I configured my project for using Django but the following error occurred    while deploying:

```
-----> Python app detected

-----> Installing python-3.6.4

-----> Installing pip

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pipenv-to-pip", line 23, in <module>

main()

File "/app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/vendor/pipenv-to-pip", line 11, in main

lockfile = json.load(f)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load

parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads

return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode

obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in   raw_decode

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

!     Push failed
```

Same problem occurres when i'm trying to install modules "**gunicorn**" and "**django-heroku**" thgrough "**pipenv**". But when i'm use just "**pip3**" it's install as usuall.

The contents of the Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.6.4"
```

The contents of the Pipfile.lock:

```
[requires]
python_full_version = "3.6.4"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`.

Comment: Those files are basically empty. Are you trying to install any libraries? Where are `gunicorn`, `django-heroku`?

Comment: Gunicorn contains in **/home/far/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages**, django-heroku in **/home/far/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from django->django-heroku)**. But there are pip's installs, not pipenv.

Comment: That's where they are on your local machine. But if you want them to be [installed on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#build-behavior) you need to add them to your `requirements.txt` file (to use `pip`) or your `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` (to use `pipenv`). It looks like you haven't done that.

Comment: Still don't work. I tried to add this packages into pipfile using pipenv install -r requirements. But when i'm trying to install gunicorn happens this:

Comment: 'pipenv install gunicorn
Installing gunicorn…
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/far/anaconda3/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/far/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/far/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    '

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing `Pipfile.lock` then `pipenv install -r requirements.txt`
or just `pipenv install` if `Pipfile` is exist